# Combining CLOB columns in Query

Tags: oracle, concatenation

I have a table with a CLOB column.  What I need to do is query the table, and combine the CLOB column of each row into a single CLOB column.

So, say I have something like:

```
ABC      CLOB_VALUE1
ABC      CLOB_VALUE2
ABC      CLOB_VALUE2
```

What I need at output is:

```
ABC      Combined Value (CLOB_VALUE1, CLOB_VALUE2, CLOB_VALUE3)
```

LISTAGG will not work due to the length, and I'm not having any luck with XMLAGG (unless I am doing it wrong).

I tried this, but it is not retrieving all the records:

```
SELECT id, XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,price_string||',') ORDER BY 
        price_date).EXTRACT('//text()').getclobval() AS daily_7d_prices
FROM daily_price_coll
WHERE price_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7
GROUP BY id;
```

I'm only getting the most recent row, when there are actually 3 rows in the table.

Any ideas?

Comment: The code you posted [seems to do what you want](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e41981db49610c347225a17a57d50922). What issue are you having with it?

Comment: There are 3 rows in the table, but it is only taking the first row, and ignoring the other 2.   Not sure why that is.   I've even tried subqueries to make sure I get all the rows, and it only processes the first one.

Comment: The example I linked to picks up all three in-scope rows. Are you sure all three of yours have dates in the last 7 days? If it isn't something that trivial then please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah, this is really strange.   The source table all has valid data and dates.   But, if I run the query as is, it works on the most recently inserted row.  If I actually code criteria, and specifically ask for a date:  TRUNC(price_date) = TO_DATE('05092022','MMDDYYYY'), then the value comes back NULL.